# Старые коммиты не мёрджатся в master из другой ветки

Tags: git, gitlab, merge

Всем привет! Вот и пришла моя очередь зарегистрироваться на Stack Overflow.
Ситуация такая, пришёл на новый проект 2-3 месяца назад, мне с порога сказали работаем в `release-*` ветках, `master` можно не трогать. Ну и вопросов особо не было.
Недавно пришлось вносить изменения для файлика `.gitlab-ci.yml` во всех ветках, а потом ещё в несколько файлов и таким образом накопилось большое количество коммитов.
Сейчас появилась необходимость актуализировать `master` ветку из условной `release-abel`.
При мёрдже из `release-abel` в `master` мёрджатся только последние коммиты.

**Какие способы есть перенести все отсутствующие коммиты из одной ветки в другую?** Вообще можно просто файлы скопировать из одной ветки и перенести, но это был бы дикий костыль. Буду благодарен за любую помощь и подсказку!

p.s. Я бы вообще удалил `master` ветку и клонировал `release-abel`, но она является защищенной.

Comment: format-patch?

`git format-patch HEAD~<указать нужное>` в ветке, из которой нужно взять коммиты

`git am -3 < <имя, полученного в прошлом шаге файла .patch>`

Comment: Спасибо! Жаль что увидел только сейчас, а так бы попробовал)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, я уже "решил" эту проблему самым ужасным костылём, который напрочь ломает суть GIT - скопировал всю директорию под актуальной веткой и вставил содержимое буфера в master ветку и новым коммитом залил всё GitLab.

Answer (score -1):

> Я бы вообще удалил master ветку и клонировал release-abel, но она является защищенной.

ну проверьте эту защиту на прочность )))

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard release-abel
git push -f
```